# Redshift - Relation does not exist on materialized view with AutoRefresh On

Tags: amazon-redshift

one of our users is getting an error (only *occasionally*) on a view that has autorefresh on. the name of the table is `vwdeviceplatform`. Is it because the view is being autofreshed at the time they are running the query? Any way to avoid that? We don't want to schedule manual refreshes.

```
Invalid operation. Relation "mv_tbl_vwdeviceplatform_0" does not exist.
```

User is using dbeaver

Comment: You're switching between the terms table and view. Is the error the name of the mv? where does `vwdeviceplatform` come in?

Comment: Take a look at the sys views and see what is going on for that mv: ```select * from svl_mv_refresh_status;```

Comment: `vwdeviceplatform` is the name of the table. The error message above is verbatim from the IDE. I assume `mv_tbl_vwdeviceplatform_0` is Redshift's internal name when it is refreshing.

I see mostly success refreshes. A few instances of `Auto refresh aborted due to excessive user workload`. But I would have thought this wouldn't interfere with endusers